# Trouble posting data from Angular/Ionic app to Laravel API

Tags: angularjs, laravel, post, eloquent

I am trying to post data from angular (Ionic mobile app) to a remote Laravel 5 REST API. This works when posting the data using Postman, but can't for the life of me get this to save into the database when trying to go through Angular front end. Here is my Angular code along with the Laravel controller for saving the data.

controllers/authentication.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.controllers.authentication', []);

app.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicLoading, AuthService) {
    $scope.loginInstagram = function() {
        AuthService.loginInstagram()
            .then(function() {
                console.log('Signed In Insta');
                $state.go("tab.home");
            });
    }
});
```

services/authentication.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp.services.authentication', []);

app.service('AuthService', function ($q, $http, $cordovaOauth, $ionicPopup) {
     var self = {
          'loginInstagram': function() {
            var d = $q.defer();

            $cordovaOauth.instagram('42e2f60b94e1487db4617a48a7000453', [], {})
                .then(function(result) {
                     console.log("Response Object -> " + JSON.stringify(result));


                    // save the access token
                    var data = { instagram_access_token: result.access_token };

                          $http.post("http://localhost:8000/api/user/signupInstagram", data).success(function(data, status) {
                           console.log(data);
                          });   
                }, function(error) {
                    console.log("Error -> " + error);
                });

               return d.promise;

        }
     };

     return self;
});
```

app/Http/Controllers/UsersController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Input;
use Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    // Gets all users in the users table and returns them
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        return $users;
    }

    public function signupInstagram() {
        $user = new User();

        $user->instagram_access_token = Input::get('instagram_access_token');

        $user->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: You got any error in console?

Comment: figured out it was a CORS issue. fixed with this https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors